# XSLT - How to sum with multiple keys in the same line in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I'm trying to get the sum of sales online and on the store, but the XML provided was a single line with multiple keys. I can get the values to generate the HTML, but the SUM function is not working, and I can't find similar problems.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TRF>
<META>
<DATE isodate="2020-07-15">15/07/2020 10:00</DATE>
<GENERATOR version="2020-07-15"/>
</META>
<DATA>
<VALUE category="ONLINE" name="AR01" value="1" date="15/07/2020"/>
<VALUE category="STORE" name="AR45" value="2" date="15/07/2020"/>
<VALUE category="STORE" name="FG32" value="3" date="15/07/2020"/>
<VALUE category="ONLINE" name="RH78" value="4" date="15/07/2020"/>
<VALUE category="STORE" name="DT34" value="5" date="15/07/2020"/>
</DATA>
</TRF>
```

XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/TRF">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>TRF Report</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Sales Report</h1>
  <table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Type of sales</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="DATA/VALUE[@category='ONLINE']">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@category"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@value"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@date"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(DATA/value [@category='ONLINE'])"/></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I fix my SUM function?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(DATA/VALUE[@category='ONLINE']/@value)"/>
```

Note that XML is case-sensitive: `value` is not the same as `VALUE`.